# Is it possible to statically link libcurl, libeay32 and ssleay32?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, openssl, libcurl

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I want to use libcurl statically (without any external dlls).

I've statically linked libcurl that I've compiled with the following command:

```
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static WITH_SSL=static WITH_DEVEL=C:\OpenSSL-Win32 VC=12 ENABLE_SSPI=no ENABLE_IDN=no ENABLE_WINSSL=no DEBUG=no MACHINE=x86 GEN_PDB=no ENABLE_IPV6=yes
```

I have downloaded OpenSSL and linked the following libs to my project:
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static\zlibeay32MD.lib
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static\ssleay32MD.lib

Everything seems to be fine, and I can successfully compile my project.
But when I run the program, I'm receiving the following error:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNVMP.png]

If I put `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to the same folder of program it works without problem.

I don't understand why it requires these dlls, I've used **WITH_SSL=static** option to compile libcurl and should load from static library, right?

Update:
C/C++ -> Command Line:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\VisualCpp\Libraries\curl-7.42.1\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ssl-static-ipv6\include\curl" /I"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\\include\openssl" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "CURL_STATICLIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\Launcher.pch"
```

Linker -> Command Line:

```
/OUT:"C:\VisualCpp\Launcher\Release\Launcher.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\VisualCpp\Launcher\Release\Launcher.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "libcurl_a.lib" "libeay32MD.lib" "ssleay32MD.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "wldap32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /NODEFAULTLIB:"libcmt.lib" /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\VisualCpp\Launcher\Release\Launcher.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\Launcher.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Comment: It is very suspicious that the error message claims `Launcher.exe` is the DLL that has a missing export. That means the IMPORTS table of Launcher.exe has a reference to itself for an exported function (and the function is not even exported by name), which implies that either the LIBs you are using are not compiled correctly, or the linker is messing up.

Comment: @Patrick: please edit your question to include that information, do not post it as comments.

Comment: Did you point your library path to C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static\ ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I solved now adding entire curl source and using static openssl libs.

Comment: @Remy - *"It is very suspicious that the error message claims Launcher.exe is the DLL that has a missing ordinal export..."* - OpenSSL still builds them. There's a step in the Win32 process for it :(